# How to skip the test generation maven goal with Spring Cloud Contract Verifier?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

I want to test a service Consumer that uses FeignClient to call another service, Producer, that I have. In order to stub the service called, I'm using spring-cloud-contract-verifier for the producer and spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner on the consumer.

My problem is that I already have written integration tests for the producer, so I'd just like to generate the stubs and skip the tests generation. Using the spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin, I've tried to set up only the goals I need, but it's still trying to run the tests anyway. I suspect I'm not setting it up correctly...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>convert</goal>
                <goal>generateStubs</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <basePackageForTests>com.example</basePackageForTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

when I run mvn clean install, it's still expecting a TestBase. How can I skip this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin/generateTests-mojo.html) you'll see that you can do a number of things. `-DskipTests`, `-Dspring.cloud.contract.verifier.skip=true`. Always read the documentation.

Comment: hi Marcin, thanks for the reply. I did read the documentation, but I don't want to skip all tests (since I have other unit and integration tests) and I do want to generate the stubs (so I can't skip the contract verifier altogether), I just want to skip the automatic test generation from the contract.

Comment: We skip the test generation when `spring.cloud.contract.verifier.skip`, `skipTests` or `maven.test.skip` are passed. You can always execute the goal related to stub generation. BTW what you're doing smells of bad practice, so I hope you know what you're doing :)

Comment: Maybe you're right. I gave up and implemented the TestBase to run the tests for my contracts, along with my other integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip contract tests use `<skipTests>true</skipTests>` in your cloud contract plugin. This will create stubs and skipTests will skip running contracts